# How do I lowercase a JSON object on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, lowercase

Here's my data:

```
Id   var_map
1    {'email_count': 3.0, 'outgoing': 90.0}
2    {'Email_Count': 5.0, 'outgoing': 91.0}
```

What I did is

`df['var_map'] = score_data['var_map'].str.lower()`

The result is different with why I expected, the error is are this

```
Id   var_map
1    NaN
2    NaN
```

How do I suppose to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach using `apply`.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"var_map": [{'email_count': 3.0, 'outgoing': 90.0}, {'Email_Count': 5.0, 'outgoing': 91.0}]})
df["var_map"] = df["var_map"].apply(lambda x: {k.lower(): v for k,v in x.items()})
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                    var_map
0  {u'outgoing': 90.0, u'email_count': 3.0}
1  {u'outgoing': 91.0, u'email_count': 5.0}
```

Comment: Works as expected

Comment: Ok, Finally, I choose this as best answer because it keep the JSON Format, and the code is met my use case

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried converting data  column to string?

```
import pandas as pd



data['var'] = data['var_map'].astype(str).str.lower()
print data
```

Comment: I'm not thinking about this method, my bad, will try

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I remove this from best answer because it not keeping the JSON format

Comment: @NabihBawazir Ah My bad. Didn't know you had to keep `dtype`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def var_map_lower(var_map):
    return {x.lower(): y for (x,y) in var_map.items()}

df['var_map'] = df['var_map'].apply(var_map_lower)
```

Can you try this?

Comment: Sorry, it's almost the same but Rakesh answer is better

Comment: Will try, rakish answer works as expected, will upvote if this work

Comment: Not working, error message `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Comment: `return {x.lower(): y for (x,y) in var_map.items()}`

Comment: I fixed my answer, it should work now, sorry, Thanks Rakesh